# I get some error in PHP, what can I do?

Tags: php, post, calculator, hidden-field

So, I made a calculator in PHP, which writes the result and that how much time used the calculator.

The first time I get some error, but when I click any submit button, the program work perfectly. **What can I do with first time errors?**

*The program:*

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php
            $using_calculator = $_POST['using_calculator'];
            if(isset($_POST['plus'])){
                    $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                    $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                    $z = $x+$y;
                    $using_calculator++;
            }else if(isset($_POST['minus'])){
                    $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                    $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                    $z = $x-$y;
                    $using_calculator++;
            }else if(isset($_POST['multiplication'])){
                    $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                    $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                    $z = $x*$y;
                    $using_calculator++;
            }else if(isset($_POST['division'])){
                    $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                    $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                    $z = $x/$y;
                    $using_calculator++;
            }
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
            <p>
                First number: <input type="number" name="number_1"><br/>
                Second number: <input type="number" name="number_2"><br/><br/>
                <input type = "submit" name="plus" value="Plus">
                <input type = "submit" name="minus" value="Minus">
                <input type = "submit" name="multiplication" value="Multiplicate">
                <input type = "submit" name="division" value="Divide">
                <input type = "hidden" name="using_calculator" value="<?php echo $using_calculator; ?>">            
            </p>
        </form>
        <br>Result: <?php echo $z; ?>
        <br>The calculator was used <?php echo $using_calculator; ?> times
    </div>
</body>
```

I have to use hiddened input fields, but I can use functions and object. So what is the best way?

Comment: the problem starts with this line `$using_calculator = $_POST['using_calculator'];`.

Comment: Yeah, as @Fred-ii- points out, you're calling `$_POST` without looking to see if `$_POST` has been set.

Comment: you're also getting undefined variable notices too I'll bet ;-)

Comment: you've been given answers below. I doubt they fixed everything though.

Comment: What is "some" error? Can you add the error to your question.

Comment: what error are you getting???

Comment: the power is in `isset()` - `!empty()` <= *that's your answer*. But, there's an even more powerful operator.

Comment: Please update that:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <?php    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); ?>

Answer (score -1):

Its because first time variables(in your php code) is not isset. So it will display error. For example

```
 $using_calculator = $_POST['using_calculator']; // first time $_POST['using_calculator']  is not isset
```

So php will output error message first time. After submit this variables get initialized from POST. So to avoid this problem, modify the php code as shown below

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['using_calculator']))
      {
                $using_calculator = $_POST['using_calculator'];
                if(isset($_POST['plus'])){
                        $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                        $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                        $z = $x+$y;
                        $using_calculator++;
                }else if(isset($_POST['minus'])){
                        $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                        $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                        $z = $x-$y;
                        $using_calculator++;
                }else if(isset($_POST['multiplication'])){
                        $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                        $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                        $z = $x*$y;
                        $using_calculator++;
                }else if(isset($_POST['division'])){
                        $x = $_POST['number_1'];
                        $y = $_POST['number_2'];
                        $z = $x/$y;
                        $using_calculator++;
                }
        }
        ?>
```